# Output content of post excerpt into Innerblocks within Gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor

I'm building a Gutenberg custom block for pulling details from a custom post type into a Gutenberg block.  In my use case, I have a custom post type of Exercises (which is a library of things like Squats, Planks, Burpees etc) and another of 'Strength and Conditioning Plan'.

The 'Strength and Conditioning Plan' post will have this block added to it numerous times, and the reps and sets and notes for each exercise added. The idea is that the user can read their plan and see the exercises they need to do and click into the exercise to get more info about it if they need, or just look at the plan.

So far the block is working well (thanks to help on here!) but I'm having to strip out all the html content from the rendered excerpt and output it into a paragraph block inside my innerblocks.

I'd rather dump all of this into the block instead so it preserves anything we've put into the excerpt or the summary automatically created from the page as the excerpt, or maybe even some of the initial post.

What's the right way of doing this?  I can't find any examples of doing this from a quick Google, but I'm not really sure what to search for!    Do I need to some how "convert" the page content back into blocks and append them into the template?

The current set of code can be seen on [Github](https://gist.github.com/5ally/edaa7a3d788bc73efe1d8196c714327a) (thanks to Sally CJ for helping out so far!)

EDIT:  Some clarifications.

The inner block pulls the title of the "Exercise" post type, along with the featured image.  Here is what the innerblocks currently looks like:

```
const MY_TEMPLATE = [
            [ 'core/heading', { content: heading } ],
            [ 'core/image', { id: mediaID, url: mediaURL, href: exerciseLink, align: "right", sizeSlug: "medium", caption: "Click for instructions", width: 300 } ], //*
            [ 'core/paragraph', { content: strippedContent } ]
        ];
```

This means the block displays effectively a nice summary of the exercise, including a link to it and a picture.   You'll also get the excerpt which the person who created the 'Exercise' will have set up.  This might be a summary of all the info in the larger exercise post which we want to be exposed in the 'Strength and Conditioning Plan'.

Right now, I'm stripping the html from the excerpt and putting it into the paragraph block above.  (If you don't strip it, it breaks because you are putting blocks or html into a paragraph which it doesn't like!)

I could grab the html from the post and just output it into the Edit/Post output, but:

- The person setting up the plan might want to tweak it before saving it.  Having it as blocks for them makes that nice and easy.
- If I do output it straight away, the html that comes out isn't rended by the browser, I'm assuming that brackets etc are turned into & gt; etc.

Comment: the only way to put something into innerblocks is for it to be a block. Why are you needing to strip out the rendered HTML? Is there a way to state your problem using simpler more concise terms? I struggled to follow along, when you ask what is the right way to do this I'm not 100% sure what it is you're referring to, and there's a lot of implied and assumed details, gaps to fill in by reading between the lines

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the innerblocks? What are you nesting inside this block? It's extremely unclear. E.g. if it's a post you've selected why did you create an innerblocks instead of just pulling in and displaying the post? Or is it multiple posts? Or are you trying to create blocks out of a post that's selected then insert them as child blocks? This is very confusing

Comment: @delanthear One challenge you may run into with converting the excerpt to blocks is that if the excerpt changes, it won't automatically get updated in the other post. Have you looked into block [render callbacks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_block_type/__construct/) that allow you to render a block using PHP (and therefore using `the_excerpt()`)? You can use the [Latest Posts block as an example](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/latest-posts/index.php).

Comment: I left a comment on the gist, but you must never, ever, put Innerblocks next too another element. It has to be the only thing inside an element. If it shares an element with other components or tags the block will fail validation

Comment: Added more notes.  Thanks for looking!  I might be overlooking something really obvious  on this as I'm very knew to using JS like this.